# Generate name by combining list of words

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, backbone.js

So what I'm trying to do say there are some text fields where user can enter 2 or 3 words. Upon submit, take those words and try various combinations with them. Kind of like a business name generator where you type some words and it gives you a business name using combinations of those words.

Wondering if there is already a jquery plugin out there for such a thing? If not a basic code example with javascript to send me in right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I kind of doubt that you'll find a library for such a specific task.  As for a basic code exmample ...

```
$('#yourForm').submit(function() {
    var words = $('#words').val().split();
    // do whatever logic you want to combine the words
});
```